# rspec exits when program exits

Tags: ruby, rspec

When RSpec comes across `exit` in my code, it also exits and no further tests are run. Here is a distilled example:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(argv)
    @options = {}
    optparse(argv)
  end

  def optparse(argv)
    OptionParser.new do |opts|
      opts.on_tail('-h', '--help', 'Show this message') do
        puts opts
        exit
      end
    end.parse!(argv, into: @options)
  end
end
```

```
RSpec.describe Parser do
  context 'when -h is passed' do
    it 'exits cleanly' do
      expect(described_class.new(['-h'])).to raise(SystemExit)
    end
  end
  context 'when --help is passed' do
    it 'exits cleanly' do
      expect(described_class.new(['--help'])).to raise(SystemExit)
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried `exit_with_code(0)` and multiple forms of writing these two tests to get the 2nd one to run. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I replace

```
expect(described_class.new(['--help']))
```

with

```
expect { described_class.new(['--help']) }
```

it works.

And since I'm also doing other tests on the same command (in addition to the `SystemExit` check), I've had to explicitly rescue it and continue on.

```
it "other test" do
      begin
        parser.new(args)
      rescue SystemExit
      end
      expect(...)
    end
```

This pattern is kinda ugly, but works. The suppressed exception will require a rubocop override if you use rubocop, but I got that pattern from rubocop's own rspec tests, so     ¯\_(ツ)_/¯